# SED/awk remove string until first occurrence

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have string like below (one long line with a space in the middle):

```
100">16946083;Rapid_0201_Corrected_Pre_Sept12thDate.txt;5744-2;RapidReporting;RR_20160606115224556.fin.bc_lerr.xml "100">16946083;Rapid_0201_Corrected_Pre_Sept12thDate.txt;5744;RapidReporting;RR_20160606115224556.fin.bc_lerr.xml
```

I want to remove the varying length set of digits between `>` and `;` which, in this example, means remove (the first occurrence of) `16946083`.

This text is an output of my `sed` and `cut` commands.

Comment: Is that 1 line of data or 2 lines or ?? Good luck.

Comment: Check that I've interpreted your question correctly — in particular, that you've shown one line of output rather than two.

Comment: don't show us output of sed+cut for us to tack another command onto, show us the input to sed+cut so we can see how best to solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
sed -e 's/>[0-9]\+;/>;/'
```

which will find the first `>` any number of digits and the `;` and replace that whole string with just `>;`

Comment: This uses a not entirely portable notation `\+`; there are numerous versions of `sed` that won't support that.  It doesn't seem to be a problem for the OP (so it's probably GNU `sed` that's in use), but it wouldn't work as written on Mac OS X (BSD), Solaris, HP-UX, AIX — to name but 4 other Unix-like operating systems unless GNU `sed` is installed. Using `sed -e 's/>[0-9][0-9]*;/>;/'` would be portable to any version of `sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point, but the direct POSIX-compliant BRE equivalent of ERE construct `+` (and its nonstandard _GNU_ BRE form `\+`) is `\{1,\}`.

Comment: @mklement0: Choose your six-character poison: `[0-9]*` vs `\{1,\}` — you're right, of course, and I didn't cover that in my comment here.  And for longer character classes  such as `[[:alnum:][:punct:]]`, then the repeat count is shorter than the repeating the character class.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed; to put it another way: I mentioned it, because the little-known `\{1,\}` is worth knowing about as the superior alternative in more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

a more robust version will be

```
sed -r 's/>[^;]+;/>;/'
```

Comment: works ! is it anyway better than what Eric mentioned?i'm asking in terms of performance. SInce I have to do this for million rows.

Comment: I don't think performance will be noticeable different.  This will delete in case your data has more than digits.  If you want to restrict only to digits, the other alternative is better, since more restrictive.